# Controls on panel doesn't show until scroll

Tags: c++, mfc

i've created a dialog (CFormView) which holds a panel with a scrollbar.
On that panel I have another panel that holds my controls, like checkboxes and radiobuttons. When I open the dialog I only see the scrollbar until I scroll down a bit and up again, then the controls show.

Any ideas why this happens?

Form (CWnd)

```
void Form::Show()
{
        m_pclScrollbar = new CFormularScrollbar(m_pwndParent, &m_clRect);
        m_pclScrollbar->SetPanel(GetPanel(0)); //This adds the panel with my buttons etc.
        m_pclScrollbar->ScrollBarInit(); //Set length etc of the scrollbar
        m_pclScrollbar->Show(); // { ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);}
        m_pclScrollbar->m_pclPanel->UpdateWindow();

}
```

If I do like this, the controls show as they should, but ofcourse no scrollbar:

```
void Form::Show()
    {
            m_pclPanel->SetPanel(GetPanel(0)); //This adds the panel with my buttons etc.
            m_pclPanel->Show();

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use standard `CFormView` to achieve what you need? It does look like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin The dialog that I want to put my panels in is actually a CFormView. But can I put a CFormView in another CFormView?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7875/CTreePropSheetEx-an-extended-version-of-CTreePropS I believe it implements exactly what you need.